# ArrayList Integer - calculate average grade without considering extreme values

Tags: java, algorithm, average

How to  calculate average grades (arithmetic method) in such a way that the extreme grades (6) will be removed from list - and the smallest (1) will be removed from list?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class ListOfGrades
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        //Create and fill the list 
        ArrayList<Integer> grades = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        grades.add(1);
        grades.add(2);
        grades.add(3);
        grades.add(4);
        grades.add(5);
        grades.add(6);

        for(int i=0; i < grades.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Element : [" + i + "] grades " +  grades.get(i)) ;  
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Removing last Element");
        grades.remove(grades.size()-1);
        System.out.println("Now all grades are : " + grades);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Removing first Element");
        grades.remove(grades.size()-5);
        System.out.println("Now all grades are : " + grades);
    }
}
```

Comment: youre code is already removing the extreme values, what do you want it to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to efficiently compute average on the fly (moving average)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28820904/how-to-efficiently-compute-average-on-the-fly-moving-average)

Comment: The solution is the same as the linked question, except that you ignore 6 and 1.

Comment: You should use grades.remove(grades.size()-(grades.size()-1)); so it is more generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this simple code at the end of your previously written code:

```
int sum=0;
for (int i=0; i<grades.size();i++){
    sum+=grades.get(i);               //adding all the grades in variable sum
}
double avg= sum/grades.size();      //dividing the sum with total number of 
                                    //grades to calculate average
System.out.println("average grade :" + avg);
```

Comment: only one thing  in the first line it should be "double"

Comment: that will only be required when your ArrayList is of <double> type and you add decimal numbers in the array. Since you are adding whole numbers in the array only, their sum will also be a whole number always. So no need of "double" sum in this case.

Answer (score 1):

There is solution with stream api using [Collectors::averagingDouble](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#averagingDouble-java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction-):

```
Double average = grades.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(value -> value));
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried something like this :

```
 grades.stream().filter(g -> !(g == 1 || g == 6))
                   .reduce((grade, sum) -> grade + sum)
                   .map(sum -> sum / 4)
                   .orElse(0);
```