# Can't get the average for the array

Tags: java

Gives wrong answer only and I can't find the reason why? This is only part of the code but the rest was copy pasted so it does the same thing. I have tried to tweak it and find a solution online but everything seems to be in order. Maybe the counter is incorrect and can't deal with the negative numbers? The answer is always 107.19999999.

```
public class draft3 {
    public static void main (String []args) {
    
    /* Create arrays for each company*/ 
    int NL5755[] = new int[] {60, 70, -10, -12, 10};
//Assign a value of 0 to total
    double sum = 0;
    double average1=0;
{
        /*Use a counter. For i smaller than the*/ 
        /*value of the length of the array, add them to sum*/
    for(int i=0; i<NL5755.length; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + NL5755[i];

    average1 += sum / NL5755.length;
}
```

Comment: The average calculation should be *after* the loop that calculates the sum.

Comment: I'm also just going to mention that this is the _exact_ use case for [`LongAccumulator::avg`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/util/LongAccumulator.html#avg--) which would better be able to handle overflows, etc. which might come up depending on the size of the `int`s, or the number of elements involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't use brackets properly.

```java
public class draft3 {
    public static void main (String []args) {
    
    int NL5755[] = new int[] {60, 70, -10, -12, 10};
    double sum = 0;
    double average1=0;
    
    for(int i=0; i<NL5755.length; i++){
      sum = sum + NL5755[i];
    }
    average1 += sum / NL5755.length;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to calculate the average of an `array of numbers`:

1. firstly you need to sum all the numbers
2. divide the sum of all numbers by the count of numbers.

**note:** the problem with your code is that you did the average on each iteration of loop:

```
int NL5755[] = new int[] { 60, 70, -10, -12, 10 };
double sum = 0;
double average1 = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < NL5755.length; i++) {
    sum = sum + NL5755[i];
}
average1 = sum / NL5755.length;
System.out.println(average1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Other people have mentioned the fact that you should move the average calculation outside of the `for` loop, which is true if you want to calculate the average after you finish with the sum. However, if you want to calculate the average inside the `for` loop, it's possible to do with an [online algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28820904/how-to-efficiently-compute-average-on-the-fly-moving-average) (i.e. "as you go"). In that case, you'd replace your current `average1` line with:

```
average1 += (NL5755[i] - average1) / (i + 1);
```