# My Javascript AVG Calculator doesn't work. How can i fix?

Tags: javascript, function

I wanted to create a function that calculate the average between some numbers. I wanted to make it that i could put as many numbers as i wanted in the console.log but this code apparently doesn't work, when i console.log it says "infinity". Need help please

```
function avg(...args){
      return args.reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a + b / avg.length
      })
    }
    console.log(avg(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the variable `avg` does not exist, and it will default to 0. Causing it to be `Infinity`.

You also have 2 additional mistakes.

1. You have not used parenthesis, you are essentially doing `a + ( b / len )` which will lead to an incorrect answer
2. You are using incorrect formula for average, in the implementation that you are using, you should be using the running average formula : refer here : [How to calculate moving average without keeping the count and data-total?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636613/how-to-calculate-moving-average-without-keeping-the-count-and-data-total)

this would be the correct solution :

```
    function avg(...args) {
        const sum = args.reduce((a,b) => a + b , 0 );
        return sum / args.length;
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain this: `This is because the variable avg does not exist, and it will default to 0. Causing it to be Infinity.`

Comment: you can see that in your question, i like to think you tried to use `args` but made a mistake and wrote `avg` instead... which is the name of your function

Comment: please accept the answer, if this solves your problem 

Comment: thank for the clear explanation, think this is gonna fix :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce and arguments length like this. You had some mistakes in your code.

```js
const average = (...args) => args.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / args.length;

console.log(average(1,2,3,4))
```