# Average for moving items

Tags: c++, c

I need to make an efficient algorithm, for moving integers.

For e.g,,an avg of 100 items.
So as the 100 numbers come, the average for 1..100 numbers..
as 101 number comes average of 2..101..
as 102 number comes average of 3..102..

I thought of one solution but i cant come up so that minimum numbers can be stored(as after wards, i have to do in microprocessor, but first, efficient in C/C++):

Step 1: store numbers from 1..100 and take average
step 2: replace 1 by 101, and take average:   101,2,3...100
step 3: replace 2 by 102, and take average:   101,102,3,4...100

But it is not efficient, as i need to use less division operator also.

Can anyone help me out please.

Comment: google for moving average

Comment: If you store the sum (rather than the average) of the previous step, you won't have to recompute the average for all 100 numbers completely. You just substract one value from the sum and add the new value, and the you divide the sum by 100. That doesn't reduce the number of divisions, though.

Comment: You *need* to use the division operator less? Or you just feel like asking that to make the problem harder and the solution "faster"?

Comment: Is this a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990618/calculate-rolling-moving-average-in-c-or-c

Comment: @jogojapan it doesn't reduce the division, its ok, but to make it more efficient, what could be other approach. ?

Comment: @Potatoswatter in microprocessor, division takes many cycles, so it should be less as i need to make it efficient.

Comment: @user2387900: If your CPU has a hardware division unit, then it will probably be pipelined, and so the fact that it takes many cycles will affect only latency, not throughput...

Comment: "Microprocessor" is any microchip that can execute a complete instruction set. If you mean "8-bit microcontroller", then that is much more specific. But merely having certain hardware doesn't justify such a design decision, and "use division less" isn't a real engineering requirement. If you need to restrict it to shift operations or something, or if some results may be approximate, then say so.

Comment: I voted to close as a duplicate, not for a failure to demonstrate a minimal understanding, which I don't think applies here. There's certainly a failure to think, but the same applies to the answer Mitch gave and then deleted when I pointed out its obvious flaw.

Comment: If you have a continuous stream of input you can do a poor-man's average on the fly, which is basically this: `average = average * 0.99 + newvalue * 0.01` - it has a basic 'boot-up' time, but works nicely in many situations.

Comment: average = average * 0.99 + newvalue * 0.01, i did not got this perfectly...i have a stream of any random values...@paddy

Comment: i read one formula : accumulator = (alpha * new_value) + (1.0 - alpha) * accumulator,,,,but i am not understanding it ??/ from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990618/calculate-rolling-moving-average-in-c-or-c?lq=1   ...  
Do you think, keeping in the array would be the best option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do a moving average is with a moving sum. Sum the numbers n[0] through n[99] to start; the average is this sum divided by 100. For the next sum, subtract n[0] and add n[100]; divide by 100 again for the average.

This works best with integers as there won't be any rounding errors in the sum; with floating point any errors will accumulate and get worse as you go along.

If you're using positive integers, you can eliminate division by making your window size a power of 2. Using 128 instead of 100 means you can divide using a right shift of 7 on the sum.

You can also eliminate division by multiplying by the inverse. Instead of dividing by 100, multiply by 1/100. If you're working with integers you may need to use fixed point, and you may also run out of bits if you're not careful.

Comment: so u suggest after average of n[0] to n[99], i should remove n[0] and add n[100] at the n[0] position only ? and i take an array of [100]..

Comment: @user2387900 what I mean is to keep the sum from the previous calculation and just change it. So the first sum (sum0) is the total of n[0] through n[99]. The second sum (sum1) is sum0-n[0]+n[100]. The third would be sum1-n[1]+n[101]. Etc.

Answer (score 2):

Your basic approach is good: use a circular buffer with 100 elements.  A key insight: say you're at the "replace 2 by 102" stage, and 2 is 50 while 102 is 70 - the total will change by the difference of +20: you just divide the new total by 100 to get the new average, *without* adding up all the elements again.

In the unlikely event that the division is so slow it's making a significant and problematic difference to your overall performance, then there's only a couple things you could *try* (but do measure - they might actually slow you down depending on your exact hardware):

- if the range of numbers if small, you could create a lookup table (i.e. an array) from value to 100th of the value, then by adding/removing these scaled values to the total you directly maintain the average
- check whether your system is faster using float or double types (counterintuitively, some systems are)
- there are some bizarre "recipes" for division by 100 on the 'net, such as `(((((uint32_t)A * (uint32_t)0x47AF) >> 16U) + A) >> 1) >> 6` from http://embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/2009/06/division-of-integers-by-constants/

Comment: It's worth noting that this approach can leading to numerical problems in floating-point arithmetic (adding `x[n]` to the sum and then subtracting `x[n]` later may not exactly cancel).  In integer arithmetic, this works perfectly.

Comment: Also, division be exactly 100 every time doesn't account for the case where the circular buffer is not yet full. Usually that can just be called part of the program startup. And usually the buffer size can be made a power of 2 to simplify that part. Also remember to round-to-nearest by adding half the buffer size to the sum before performing floored division.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: true - I've focused on optimisations that can kick in once in steady-state mode with the buffer full.