# Finding all first elements in a vector of pairs

Tags: c++

I am trying to perform averages on some values in a vector of pairs that have the same first element, and then storing it inside of a map. For example:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, double>> test;
test.push_back(std::make_pair(1,100.0));
test.push_back(std::make_pair(1,200.0));
test.push_back(std::make_pair(1,400.0));
test.push_back(std::make_pair(2,200.0));
test.push_back(std::make_pair(2,300.0));
test.push_back(std::make_pair(3,100.0));

std::map<int, double> test2;
test2 would then contain: {{1, 233.33}, {2, 250}, {3, 100}};
```

The issue I am having is **finding all the duplicate first elements** then performing the average.

**Note**: the **test** vector is sorted using the code below:

```
std::sort(test.begin(), test.end(), 
     [](auto a, auto b) 
     {          
         return a.first < b.first;       
     });
```

Can someone explain how I should go about doing this?

Comment: Is it pure coincidence the vector in your example is already sorted by obj.first ?

Comment: First sort the vector by the first element and then iterate over it and calculate the average value. Of course, if it's already sorted you don't need to do it.

Comment: @WhozCraig it's not already sorted.

Comment: My approach: Use a [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) to iterate over the vector and sum up all values with same first element. After the first element changes reset the sum, the counter and store the value in a map.

Comment: Related: [Calculate rolling / moving average in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990618/)

Comment: Notice that regular comparison would do the job too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your vector sorted sequentially by the first pair element you can do something like:

```
double sum {0.0};
int count {0};
int key {pair[0].first};

for (auto pair : vec) {
  if (pair.first != key) {
    map.insert(key, sum / count);
    key = pair;
    sum = 0.0;
    count = 0;
  }
  sum += pair.second;
  count++;
}

if (count > 0) {
  map.insert(key, sum / count);
}
```

Comment: Nice,  If there were only two entries with the same key, the if statement never becomes true, how do I check whether they key is the last element in the map?

Comment: Check the count (incase vec was empty) then insert then final entry.